# sqllite select rows until a total amount is met in a column

Tags: sqlite

I've seen the similar problem with mysql, but I barely could find any solution for the problem with sqllite.

My sample table,

```
-----------------------------
ID   | Product Name   | Price
-----------------------------
1            A           2
2            B           2
3            C           1
4            D           3
5            E           2
```

Here I need to get the rows until the total for the price column is equal or smaller than 5 in ascending order.

Comment: equal or smaller? You meant probably equal or greater?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do a Running total using the `Product ID` and `ORDER BY Product ID` like the one below:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.ProductName, p1.Price,
(SELECT SUM(p2.Price) FROM Products p2 WHERE p1.ID >= p2.ID  ORDER BY p2.ID ) as RunningTotal
FROM Products p1
WHERE RunningTotal <= 5
ORDER BY p1.ID
```

See [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/63ef3/2)

Or using the `Price` and `ORDER BY Price` like one below:

```
SELECT p1.ID, p1.ProductName, p1.Price, 
(SELECT SUM(p2.Price) FROM Products p2 WHERE p1.Price >=  p2.Price ORDER BY Price ) 
as RunningTotal
FROM Products p1
WHERE RunningTotal <= 5
ORDER BY p1.Price;
```

See [2nd Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/63ef3/3)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to do it in code as SQLite does not support an easy way to do cumulative sums as far as I know. You can create an index on the Price column.

Then running a query like

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY Price
```

Note that this will not eagerly fetch all rows from the database, but just provide you with the cursor. Keep fetching the next row from the cursor until you reach the desired sum.